# Image not showing up on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

The image does not appear in a mobile browser. It does show up on a regular browser (PC) or on inspect element (mobile view), but it does not show on a real phone.

HTML:

```
<div class="image_wrap">
        <img src="img/about/600x600.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="main" data-img-url="img/about/1.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tomer_tm_hero_header_wrap .image_wrap{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 38px;
    position: relative;
}
    .tomer_tm_hero_header_wrap .image_wrap .main{
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        bottom: -8px;
        left: 8px;
        right: -8px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        border-radius: 100%;
    }
    .tomer_tm_hero_header_wrap .image_wrap img{
        min-width: 100%;
        border-radius: 100%;
        border: 8px solid rgb(227, 135, 45);
    }
```

Comment: What mobile browser are you using?

Comment: it appears in chrome tools (iphone X compatibility view)

Comment: I'm using chrome on mobile. It does show up when I'm using chrome tools but not on mobile.

Comment: If you try it through your mobile so it really won't show up. But it appears in chrome tools. That's weird.

Comment: I suggest to post the rest of your *CSS* code (i.e. what you call "media queries") here in the question and *not*  as a JS fiddle's *HTML* code (!!??), and also add the HTML code...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9zevkjxr/

Comment: I still haven't managed to solve the problem, will appreciate any help :)

Comment: @Maske13 well this it is hard to help you if I can't reproduce the problem. I am using an iPhone 6s with Chrome and the image appears as it should. I also used an android tablet and it worked fine.

Comment: I also wasn't able to reproduce the problem... I tested it on an iPhone with Safari and it works. Even in your fiddle, the only reason why the image doesn't show is because you have a relative path to the image.

Comment: I've tried this (both on inspect element as well as on my samsung galaxy 9 plus) and your code works.

Comment: I tried it on chrome and opera browser in an android mobile and the image shows up fine without any problem. Can you give us more details like, what mobile you are using and the version of chrome. And did you check in Incognito mode?

Comment: Your image is Fine. It is showing on mobile device on chrome.

Comment: @Maske13 have you tested it with a different mobile device on both the same and a different network?  Tried with wifi and mobile data?  I wonder if the issue is specific to your device.

Comment: Did you go to the website before you had the image up? Did you try completely clearing your mobile browser history, cookies, cache or trying in icognito/private window?

Comment: is your problem resolved? Can you share on which phone you are facing this issue?

Comment: If this is still an issue; can you share which phone and browser you're struggling with? I've opened your site on an iPhone X and iPhone 8 using both Chrome and Safari in Browserstack and can see no issue. Alternatively, have you disabled images in your mobile browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an addition to the answer provided by Marco Escaleira.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by using a div with a data-img-url? Are you using JS to replace the div with a valid html element? If you are we need to see the rendered html. If not see the answer below.

The only reason I can think to do this is to handle a responsive image issue or to have a background image that you can position properly. Both of those cases are better serve with cleaner more semantic HTML and they would become accessible.

### 1: responsive image using

In this case you would use a `picture` tag with image source sets. This would allow you to swap the image based on the size required per device and provide you with a new element that you can position. The benefit of this is you get a working fallback and can use webp and jpg / png for performance enhancements.

### 2: needing a new element to position

In this case I would recommend using a sudo selector such as `::after` or `:: before`. You can then use css to inject the image as a background and position it where you like. This will solve an accessibility issue as the image (which I am assuming is for presentation only) will no longer be picked up by assistive devices.

For more info I'd recomend looking at https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/. It's a great rundown on responsive images.

Answer (score 2):

Why just don't you substitute that:

```
<div class="main" data-img-url="img/about/1.jpg"></div>
```

with:

```
<img class="main" src="img/about/1.jpg" alt="me" />
```

And dont forget do add `position: relative` to the `.image_wrap` class so that your `.main` stays absolute to the parent element and not the whole page.

Comment: I think it's not related to the question, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try use `background: url(img/about/1.jpg)` in css in `.tomer_tm_hero_header_wrap .image_wrap .main` instead of using `data-img-url`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue is but when I go to your site, tomer.info, on two different devices (iPhone XR and Galaxy S9) your image shows up. When I go to your fiddle page it doesn't... I did however notice on the fiddle that you have some CSS pointing to an SVG and I don't see that in your HMTL which could be messing with some of your styles. Just a heads up.

Answer (score -1):

are you not using Media Queries for your website to be responsive? If not you should use them definitely. Otherwise if you are using them then you did something wrong inside it but i'd have to see the media queries to help.